# riak-admin fails on osx 10.8.5

Tags: riak

I'm trying to install riak on my OSX 10.8.5, but when using the command `riak-admin test` it always fail. I can't find a solution for it!

Also using `sudo riak-admin test` doesn't help it.

I have installed riak(1.4.2) through brew.

```bsh
>riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
>riak ping
pong
>riak-admin test
Failed to write test value: {error,timeout}%
```

I have installed riak(1.4.2) precompiled tarball using wget

```bsh
>curl -O http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.basho.com/riak/1.4/1.4.2/osx/10.8/riak-1.4.2-OSX-x86_64.tar.gz
>tar xzvf riak-1.4.2-osx-x86_64.tar.gz
>cd riak-1.4.2
>bin/riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
>bin/riak ping
pong
>bin/riak-admin test
Failed to write test value: {error,timeout}%
```

I have install riak(1.4.1) precompiled tarball using wget

```bsh
>curl -O http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.basho.com/riak/1.4/1.4.1/osx/10.8/riak-1.4.1-OSX-x86_64.tar.gz
>tar xzvf riak-1.4.1-osx-x86_64.tar.gz
>cd riak-1.4.1
>bin/riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
>bin/riak ping
pong
>bin/riak-admin test
Failed to read test value: {error,{insufficient_vnodes,0,need,1}}%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Following [this procedure http://docs.basho.com/riak/...](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X) solved my issue.
It has to do with the Open Files Limit on mac OSX.

### Before

> To check the current limits on your Mac OS X system, run:

```
>launchctl limit maxfiles
maxfiles    256      unlimited
```

### Edit (or create) /etc/launchd.conf

> Edit (or create) /etc/launchd.conf and increase the limits. Add lines
>   that look like the following (using values appropriate to your
>   environment):

```
limit maxfiles 16384 32768
```

### Restart the system

> Save the file, and restart the system for the new limits to take
>   effect. After restarting, verify the new limits with the launchctl
>   limit command:

```
>launchctl limit maxfiles
maxfiles    16384    32768
```